# OpenGL/DevIL: Texture Clipped has white around the edges

Tags: opengl, rendering, game-engine, devil

I'm using DevIl to load openGL textures, which is chopped up into sprites by metadata. The problem is, the chopped segment has white around the edges (see below):

[image]

This sprite is 64 x 64, so no pixel padding procedures have been used. The spritesheet is cramped, all of the sprites are assembled right next to each other (as opposed to separating them).

Is it possible that there is a configuration that I am missing in my DevIL texture loading function? Or is it a rendering feature of OpenGL?

Comment: What is your texture filter? Does setting it to `GL_NEAREST` solve your problem? If so, I have written extensively about the cause of this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611745/opengl-black-lines-in-between-tiles/19612007#19612007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your texture filter? Does setting it to GL_NEAREST solve your problem? If so, I have written extensively about the cause of this problem:

[opengl, Black lines in-between tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611745/opengl-black-lines-in-between-tiles/19612007#19612007).