# Clamp to edge VS Clamp

Tags: opengl, image-processing, opencl

I am working on an OpenCL project, trying to implement Gaussian filter. At this moment I am stuck at cl_adressing_mode definition, especially I don't get the difference between CL_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE and CL_ADDRESS_CLAMP.

The definition of cl_addressing_mode states: the addressing mode specifies what to do when the coordinate falls outside the range of [0.0, 1.0](for normalized coordinates) or [0,
dimension - 1](for non-normalized coordinates) but still, doesn't specify what do its parameters do when I apply a convolution matrix to my image input.

Answer (score 2):

The details of image samplers are described in section 6.12.14.1 of the OpenCL 1.2 specification. In particular, table 6.22 on page 295 has the information you are after:

> CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE – out-of-range image coordinates are clamped to the extent.
>
> CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP – out-of-range image coordinates will return a border colour.

The definition of 'border colour' is in the following section (it depends on the channel order).

Comment: What does "coordinates are clamped to the extent" mean? Can you give me an example please

Comment: @NicoMkhatvari: Actually, what it really means is that instead of clamping to the ***boundary*** of an image, it clamps to the center of the last pixel in the image. I have a diagram in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323188/texture-coordinates-near-1-behave-oddly/19323954#19323954) that explains what boundary coordinates are.

Comment: Is this relation correct Wrapping_border = clamp_to_edge and clamp = extending_border?

Comment: That sounds backwards to me. Clamping to the edge removes border pixels completely. By that, I mean even if you linearly interpolate the 4 nearest neighbor texels, because the texel addresses are clamped to the center of the texels on the edge, the edge texel gets a weight of **1.0** and border texels (if they even exist) are never part of the filtering calculation. Ordinarily, if you did not clamp to the edge, 1-3 of the neighbor texels would come from the border. The closer your coordinate is to exactly **0.0** or **1.0** the more the border color would weigh into the final color.