# What should a G-Buffer commonly include in a deferred rendering process?

Tags: opengl, graphics, deferred-rendering

I am trying to implement a simple deferred renderer using OpenGL and having read various tutorials and papers describing the topic, most only offer very minimalistic or abstract description to the structure of a G-Buffer - usually containing diffuse, depth and normal buffers.

Yet even a simple graphics engine wouldn't be complete without some sort of material rendering, using textures, adjustable specular lighting and more. Adding additional buffers for all properties would obviously bloat the G-Buffer a lot so what is the preffered method of obtaining all that per-material data in the second rendering pass?

In my OpenGL implementation i use Framebuffers rendering diffuse, normal and depth to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` and `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` respectively. Is there a way to even store an ID or similar for materials, preferrably in OpenGL 3.3 core?

Comment: Most sophisticated implementations will cram other info into the 3-component G-Buffer images to make them 4-component. I myself have encoded specular into the diffuse color map and material ID into the normal map in the past using this technique. Have a look at papers written by CryTek, Guerrilla and Epic Games, they are very open on this and some of them even contribute to books like GPU Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to store material ID is by passing that ID to fragment shader as a uniform, and write it to your G-buffer. Assuming that your buffer is 4 channels RGBA8, and material ID is unsigned 8-bit int, which supports 265 materials, your fragment shader in G-buffer pass will look something like this (pseudo):

```
uniform uint inMatId;
uniform sampler2D inTexture;
void main()
{
    outputColor = vec4(texture(ourTexture, TexCoord).rgb, inMatId/255); 
}
```

Of course, the best way to draw like this is to sort objects by material then draw. Notice that I devided the material Id by 255 to map it to [0,1] range. During the shading pass you can read it back by multiplying by 255. The same approach can be use for pretty much every other types of data that you need.

Comment: is dividing by 255 and later multiplying by the same really going to work on all openGL implementations? it feels a little weird to me, since it gets casted to a float in the [0,1] range as you said, which i would assume is prone to errors during the transfer process depending on implementation.

Comment: @nOvoid: Assuming the output is an 8-bit per-component fixed-point image (which is usually the case) that will create no problems at all. That is how the hardware converts between fixed-point and floating-point _(so ironically what ends up happening here is the shader converts to foating-point for output, then the GPU converts back to fixed-point for storage)_. But intuitively, I think the compiler will not like that pseudo-code unless you make the **255** constant floating-point.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman in fact i just implemented this solution and for some reason i dont get expected results. what i did was output `mat_id/255.0f` into my normal buffer's alpha (which is `SRGB8_ALPHA8`) and then read it in my second pass via `int mat_id = int(texture2D(normal_texture, uv).a *255.0f);` yet the id is slightly different, i assume because the integer cast might have been done wrong due to float precision errors? does that mean i have to round it first?

Comment: @nOvoid: Well, texture filtering can really foul up this sort of thing. I don't know the specifics of your situation, but using a `GL_NEAREST` filter or adjusting the coordinates to use texel centers may fix your problem. If you're stretching a quad over your viewport and using the texture coordinates [**0.0**,**1.0**], you actually will not sample at texel centers, and that introduces texture interpolation. [See here for an explanation of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323188/texture-coordinates-near-1-behave-oddly/19323954#19323954).

Comment: Also consider using texelFetch